# Upgrading from rails 3.2 to 4.1, no scss nor css being loaded

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sass, asset-pipeline

i'm upgrading from rails 3.2 to 4.1 and am having trouble seeing any of my css/scss on my page!

I ran `rake assets:precompile` and got this back:

```
    Using Node ExecJS runtime
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:38.707329 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-447971b753b8b31b235edcb58bd6d465.eot
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:39.311546 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/application-c560138eebdd44e87d4eeecdbe93b4a6.js
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:39.518320 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/tinymce/plugins/uploadimage/dialog-6ac59fd1265fccc5bccc556ef7f3eab1.html
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:39.521406 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/tinymce/plugins/uploadimage/editor_plugin-03dac2c96193a3e4b98f963371b21fbe.js
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:39.525538 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/tinymce/plugins/uploadimage/img/uploadimage-edaf87c2fd2a37cca45d6fd8ae7f9fb3.png
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:39.565577 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/tinymce/plugins/uploadimage/langs/de-704d6ba19438c991c390bf91e1345c85.js
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:39.573775 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/tinymce/plugins/uploadimage/langs/en-c4e2dee47859faa7e6f5bbdb7614d9d6.js
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:39.581915 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/tinymce/plugins/uploadimage/langs/es-b90c482aa2c2ba703f15341fba30d2c8.js
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:39.589320 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/tinymce/plugins/uploadimage/langs/fr-9b3196384d50341bf8ecb0b6de311ad0.js
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:39.596807 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/tinymce/plugins/uploadimage/langs/nb-840fd15d2770e1d68c5de2e472278e98.js
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:39.603680 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/tinymce/plugins/uploadimage/langs/pt-2de8bbc698da9359d33ec852124a9405.js
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:39.611442 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/tinymce/plugins/uploadimage/langs/pt_BR-6bcc960d66bc0f8738f50dd94a77dfcb.js
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:39.617844 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/tinymce/plugins/uploadimage/langs/ru-ee4a494d9c2cfe2b380fb8b435afeb50.js
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:39.626124 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/tinymce/plugins/uploadimage/langs/zh-cn-9a03082556cbc18ea190f13555009a19.js
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:39.633560 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/tinymce/plugins/uploadimage/plugin-b2f1ab5f2e17848bc3520cb4e2e95caa.js
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:39.829492 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-49defa2606c470b7e271bda641081095.eot
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:39.837271 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-bc775956a5e2bde4082f030d6fbd8df8.svg
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:39.846107 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-1c6c3c9ade9c18d3ae6c132dfc5bac2e.ttf
I, [2014-09-17T14:33:39.853896 #32048]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/jay/Code/app/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-f744430ad26d70714cb3deda74cdfd4d.woff
cp public/assets/chosen-sprite-462aa0a3b4ce745fed7a76d4f0e83ceb.png public/assets/chosen-sprite.png
cp public/assets/chosen-sprite-6b7a8d08496e99225590e52a36a8a913.png public/assets/chosen-sprite.png
cp public/assets/chosen-sprite@2x-8bce01a186903a709c6a6d75394401cb.png public/assets/chosen-sprite@2x.png
cp public/assets/chosen-sprite@2x-a6831d7d7ea017068fccad81a697d138.png public/assets/chosen-sprite@2x.png
```

My log looks like this :

```
  Started GET "/stylesheets/app_responsive.scss.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:11 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/app_responsive.scss.css"):
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.4.245) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.4.245) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.4.245) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.4.245) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.4.245) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.4.245) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.4.245) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.4.245) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.4.245) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  heroku-deflater (0.5.3) lib/heroku-deflater/skip_binary.rb:19:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.4.245) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/deflater.rb:25:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.4.245) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  heroku-deflater (0.5.3) lib/heroku-deflater/serve_zipped_assets.rb:50:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.4.245) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.4.245) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  airbrake (4.1.0) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:16:in `_call'
  airbrake (4.1.0) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.4.245) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack-mini-profiler (0.9.2) lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:300:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.4.245) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.4.245) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  script/rails:6:in `require'
  script/rails:6:in `<main>'


  Rendered /Users/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (93.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (420.5ms)


Started GET "/assets/junto-logo-full.svg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:11 -0700


Started GET "/assets/users/default_avatar.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:11 -0700


Started GET "/assets/homepage/script-blogpost.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:11 -0700


Started GET "/assets/campaigns/the-driver/carousel1.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:11 -0700


Started GET "/assets/homepage/ayp-calltoaction.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:11 -0700


Started GET "/assets/modernizr.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/jquery.min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/jquery-migrate-min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/abstract-chosen.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/chosen.jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/select-parser.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/chosen-jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/jquery/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/affix.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/alert.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/button.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/carousel.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/collapse.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/tab.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/transition.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/modal.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/popover.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-sprockets.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/jquery.Jcrop.min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/jquery.NobleCount.min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:12 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/jquery.appear-1.1.1.min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/jquery.multiselect.min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/jquery.selectboxes.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/jquery.timeago.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/jquery.tools.min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/jquery.typing.min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/jquery.validate.min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/jquery.videoBG.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/jquery_autoscale.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/overlay.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/select2/select2.min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/spin.min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/swfobject.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/lib/waypoints.min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/general/handlers/registration.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/general/namespace.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/general/notable_count_functions.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/general/utils.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/general/video.min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/layout.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/k_temp.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/pages/jquery.jcarousel.min.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/pages/jquery.pikachoose.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/pages.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700


Started GET "/assets/default_project_image.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-17 14:56:13 -0700
```

Could somebody please help me out?  Am I compiling assets wrong? Is a gem outdated, or am I just missing something?

Comment: What folder is /stylesheets/app_responsive.scss.css in?

Comment: app/assets/stylesheets/app_responsive.scss.css.  It's called like this: `= stylesheet_link_tag "app_responsive.scss", :media => "all"`

Comment: I figured it out, i had to call `= stylesheet_link_tag"app_responsive"`

Comment: Nice. You should post that as an answer and mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `= stylesheet_link_tag "app_responsive.scss", :media => "all"` I had to use `= stylesheet_link_tag "app_responsive", :media => "all"`

That fixed my problem.